# Convert sp automatically to each other in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi

Tags: android, text-size

I set `textSize` in my `TextView` at `14sp` in mdpi mode and I dont know what is the best size preference(sp) for `textSize` in ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi modes.

Is there any way to convert sp automatically  to each other in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi modes?

Comment: You can use dimensions with qualifiers ldpi, mdpi, etc.. declare it on differente dimens files then use @dimens/text_size, aldo, 14sp are scalable and I think it will look different on dimmensions (else it will look equals at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this depedency to handle to all dp and sp :
    **implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'** and use in the xml like this:- android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp" also in the java/ kotlin file like this R.dimen._100sdp.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to.  Sp is automatically scaled to different densities.  Its like dp in that way.  The difference is that its also scaled by a factor in the settings the user can adjust, in order to make the text easier to read for people with sight issues.

Answer (score 2):

`sp` is a density-independent measurement, like `dp`, so there's no need to have a separate size for the other modes. The difference between `dp` and `sp` is just that `sp` includes a scale factor based on the user's font size preference.